# Is there a way to blacklist extensions in Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, attachment

I have an app that must accept *almost* every file type except those known to be malitious (ie exe, dll, bat, etc).  I am using Paperclip and am wondering if there is a way to do this.  Following the commit on github, https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/020625921adae884534608d76c11f65692e4bbec, it looks like it may be possible.  But I am unsure.

**UPDATE:** I could not find a Paperclip way of doing things, however I did add this custom validation:

```
  def extension_not_blacklisted?
 #An attempt to make a blacklist command when saving...
 forbiden_types = Array.new()
 forbiden_types << "jpg" << "exe" <<"dll" 
 path_array = attachment.to_s.split(".")
 extension = path_array.pop
 extension_with_extras = extension.to_s.split("?")
 extension = extension_with_extras[0]

forbiden_types.each do |f|
  if f == extension
  errors.add(:attachment,'FORBIDEN FILE EXTENSION: ' + extension)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom validation method is probably the only way. At least for now, Paperclip can validate only content types, with something like:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => ['image/png', 'application/pdf'], :message => 'should be a valid type'
```

and it validates inclusion, not exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression that uses negative lookahead:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => /\/(?!(php|pl|exe|pm|cfm|asp)$)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `before_post_process` filter and return `false` if the extension is in your blacklist - returning false will prevent the rest of the processing chain from executing.

See the bottom of this page for an example on checking for a valid file size.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation

Comment: The before_post_process seems only to apply to making the thumbnail for the image, as I returned false and it still uploads the big image, but does not generate a thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

## Create a custom validation.

```
BANNED_FILE_EXTENSIONS = [
  ".exe",
  ".js",
  ".sh",
  ".shar"
].freeze


validate :file_extension_is_allowed


def file_extension_is_allowed
  errors.add( :attachment, "is not an allowed file extension" ) if BANNED_FILE_EXTENSIONS.include?( File.extname( self.attachment_file_name ) )
end
```